# Android ViewPagerIndicator rendering issue on smaller resolutions

Tags: android, tabs, viewpagerindicator

My app has a `TabPageIndicator` strip provided by [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator), with multiple (currently 4, but increasing) tabs, with different text (and thus tab widths).

On a Nexus 4, my tabs with longer text are truncated.  eg: 'Stonehenge' => 'Stonehen'.  The interesting thing is that the tabs are all the same width; 192 pixels.  This makes sense given that the width of the Nexus4 is 768px (4 * 192) but the `mMaxTabWidth` field is set to 432px:

```
TabPageIndicator.java: 102
mMaxTabWidth = (int)(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 0.4f);
```

Looking at the result returned by `TabView::getMeasuredWidth()` when called in the `TabView::onMeasure()` (`TabPageIndicator:273`) all of the text (even those strings which do not get truncated) measured widths are > 200px which is obviously greater than 192px

On my Nexus 5 device each of the tabs render the text without truncation but the tabs are all different widths.  This is to be expected since the tabs have text of different lengths, so the longer strings need more space.

At first I thought it was an OS issue (calculating tab widths differently), but my Nexus 5 running KitKat or Lollipop renders correctly, whereas my Nexus 4 running KitKat or Lollipop **does not** render correctly.  Therefore I'm thinking it's an issue caused by lower resolutions.

Given the `TabPageIndicator` is a `HorizontalScrollView` on the Nexus4, if all the tabs don't fit on the screen that's OK; the user can scroll.  It's important that the text renders correctly.

What do I need to do to get the text to not be truncated on Nexus4 devices?

Comment: cant you use dp instead of px? :D

Comment: @edwinj By the time we get to onMeasure I believe the units used by the OS are pixels because we're figuring out how much space all the views on the screen will take.